# How many neighbors can I have?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

My town is starting to look pretty crowded in places.  What is the maximum number of NPC residents my town can have?  Is there anything I can do to affect this?

Comment: IF it's like the old games, the better your town environment is (more trees, flowers), the more neighbors will move in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have up to 10. 9 will move in on their own. You have the option of moving in a 10th in if you have built a campsite and are chummy with the visitor.

http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_New_Leaf#Villagers

Comment: hm... 2 wikias with 2 different numbers.... I guess we cant be sure without testing then.

Comment: Japanese guide books show only ten. http://www.belltreeforums.com/showthread.php?63845-I-m-ready-for-anything!&p=1280399&viewfull=1#post1280399

Comment: I have 10 villiagers, me, and one other human player who lives in my town (my girlfriend's save file). Maybe that's where the 12 comes from?

Answer (score 2):

you can have a maximum of 12 villagers. They will move in when your town becomes "better" more trees, different fruits, lots of flowers, no weeds, upgraded stores, etc.

if you have 12 villagers and a new one wants to move in, one will move out.

http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Animal_Crossing:_New_Leaf#Villagers

Comment: Your link seems to be saying 9. I'm not sure where 12 came from.